# JQuery UI Duplicating items when sorting

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am working on a project in which I must build a list of items from a list of products and then be able to sort those items once they are in my shopping cart.

I have put together some code and have got most things working, but when I start to sort my shopping cart, the items are being duplicated.

```
$(function () {
    $("#dragable div").draggable({
        appendTo: "body",
        helper: "clone",
    });

    $("#cart ol").droppable({
        activeClass: "ui-state-default",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        accept: function (draggable) {
            return $(this).find("#copy-" + draggable.attr("id")).length == 0;
        },
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            tag = ui.draggable;
            tag.clone().attr("id", "copy-" + tag.attr("id")).appendTo(this);
            $(this).find(".placeholder").hide();
            //alert($( this ).sortable('toArray'));
        },
    }).sortable({
        items: "div:not(.placeholder)",
        sort: function () {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
        },
    });

    $("#products").droppable({
        accept: "#cart div",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            ui.draggable.remove()
            if ($("#counter div").length < 2) 
                $("#cart ol").find(".placeholder").show();        
        }
    });
});
```

It may be easier to see the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/cW832/4/

Any help is greatly appreciate and thank you in advance!

Comment: where is your draggable ,droppable library , in fiddle,there is no draggable,droppable ,sorting option ,sorry

Comment: I have it loaded in my header eg. <script src="../ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>, <script src="../ui/jquery.ui.droppable.js"></script> etc.

Comment: then add it (path) in jsfiddle at the left side